# how to use a string as a key which typed key is literal

Tags: typescript

```js
type AType = {

    'v1.41': {}
}

const x:AType = {
  'v1.41': {}
}

x[version] << error
```

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Comment: please include the `version`

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgUwE4QJbgFw2k1YDmMAvDAORwCMAdACwWkDcAUE1AJ4AOCMAggCqduJAN5MYZSrXpZhAX2biA2gGsEbLDjz4AujPlN9TUJFgAPLP0HEYo8eWp1SegDQHmTU4sQp0YbcyA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: the issue was that the version type was string and should be a literal too.

Comment: should I write the answer then?

Comment: not sure how relevant it is for the community, as it is a pretty beginner / stupid question. But feel free =)

Comment: agree, let's close the question then